# Finding Z value difference between consecutive GPS points

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to abstract a value from a column with the next value from the same column in QGIS by using python.

I have a table with points with X,Y,Z from GPS tracklog. I sort them by time and I'm trying to find the Z value difference between points.

Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: I am trying to think of any possible usecase, but can't come up with one. Could you explain, why you're trying to achieve this?

Comment: I have a table with points with X,Y,Z and I'm trying to find the Z difference between points.

Comment: And how do you determine the sequence of points? Do they form a line?

Comment: No, from GPS tracklogs. I sort them by time and I'm trying to find the Z value difference

Comment: This is not a QGIS answer but, you can store your data in PostGIS and use PostgreSQL `lead` function ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)). For QGIS, some plugins (e.g. : Sort and Number) store a rank in a field function of another (gps time for example), and after, you can compute your distance with something like : `attribute(get_feature(@layer, 'rank_field', "rank_field" + 1), 'distance_field') - "distance_field"`. With Python, iterate over features, and make as computations as you want.

Comment: Does points have unique value? And what kind of date type does the table have? "31/01/2020" or "01/31/2020 00:00:00" or etc. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the layer. After changing date column name, run the following script after.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# create feature list
fs = list(layer.getFeatures())

# sort the list by date.
fs.sort(key=lambda f: f["DATE_TIME_COLUMN"])

# if you need to reverse sorting use this:
# fs.sort(key=lambda f: f["DATE_TIME_COLUMN"], reverse=True)

####
z_diffs = []
for i, f in enumerate(fs):
    if i == len(fs) - 1:
        break
    diff = fs[i+1].geometry().get().z()- fs[i].geometry().get().z()
    z_diffs.append(diff)

print(z_diffs) 
####

### OR you can use this list comprehension instead of the for loop above ###
# z_diffs = [fs[i].geometry().get().z()- fs[i-1].geometry().get().z() for i, f in enumerate(fs)][1:]
# print(z_diffs) 
###


# Result for the image below:
# [-50.0, -40.0, 20.0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Kadir!! That works perfectly!!!

Comment: Done, sorry I'm new here :)